How to use in UDF the Evaluate function for an Excel array formula string longer than 255 character
For a time I use an UDF which is similar to LAMDA function, where the input formula is a string. This works always without any issue. Within the UDF the function string is processed with the Excel EVALUATE function and returns the correct result for single and array values too. But now I have a formula which is longer than 255 character natively. Reserch results advise to set an unused cell via the UDF implicitely with the formula, calculate it and obtain the result for further processing. Now this works with the long formulas too, but the issue is that if the formula returns an array (as an array function), the formula should be also an array formula in the cell (curly braces wrapped). This is what I couldn't achieve.
This is the simple working demo code of the trial:
Function one()

Evaluate "two()"
one = "DONE"
End Function

Function two()

a = "=Len(""this is a very very very very very long long long string which must be resolved in a value which is over 255 vcharacter""&" & """ length but i need the total length of the value. My problerm is that I have to do it with a user defined function and cannot separate the length of it. It will works for me? This was my question."")"
Range("a1").Formula = a
Debug.Print a

End Function

On the worksheet code module
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$E$6" Then
Calculate
End If
End Sub


In the sheet:



A
B
C
D
E





14
14





54






34






2






134






87


=one()



Cell E6 is the UDF caller and cell A1 is for the result. In this case return 315.



A
B
C
D
E




315
14
14





54






34






2






134






87


DONE



The issue is if I change the line
Range("a1").Formula = a
to
Range("a1").FormulaArray = a
the code runs without error, but cell A1 remains empty.
How can set the cell formula as an array formula. This is in Excel which use CSE.(Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

If you're using Worksheet_Change then do you need the Evaluate at all?  You can run code directly from the event...

Worksheet_change is for recalculating the sheet, because it is not done automatically.

I get that, but could you use VBA to calculate the result of the long formula, plug that in, and then calculate the rest of the sheet?

The formula is a dynamic string which was calculated with EVALUATE. But when the string is longer than 255 char. it cannot be done directly. Therefore try this workaround.

Maybe you can show us your actual use case?  There are obvious workarounds for the posted example...

A general formula looks like this: =LAMBDA("x","y","UDF1(longformula with param **x**,**y** and other Excel,UDF2,UDF3)")  . The target is not to calculate separatly each function but with only one complex function. This is a project with more than 20 UDFs and about 200KB text. This mod. should cover to furcate when string is longer than 255 and return the single or array result. The functions and parameters are always different and cannot be defined beforehand. This works if only a single value is the result. What I would need is the array of the result like this d=evaluate("B1:B3*B4:B6")

The argument to the EVALUATE function cannot be longer than 255 characters, but the result can be longer. You can replace portions of the argument in the EVALUATE function with defined names that can refer to both ranges and formulas.
Examples:
In B1 formula:
=REPT("XYZ",100)
In B2 formula:
=REPT("KLMN",65)
I named cells B1 and B2 a and b, and the formulas aa and bb, respectively.
Both of the following functions work in a worksheet:
Function MyEval()
    MyEval = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate("a & b")
End Function
Function MyEval1()
    MyEval1 = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate("aa & bb")
End Function

In cells B7:B9 and B10:B12 I have placed long texts.
The macro inserts an array formula:
Sub ArrayForm()
    Range("B14:B16").FormulaArray = "=B7:B9 & B10:B12"
End Sub

The EVALUATE function can return an array result:
Function MyEval2()
    MyEval2 = Application.ThisCell.Parent.Evaluate("B7:B9 & B10:B12")
End Function



What I need is that  the long text is the formula itself as seen in the example, which is correctly placed in cell A1. The issue is that if it is an array formula it cannot be calculated because I cannot set it as an array formula via the FormulaArray property.

Not sure I completely follow the issue but here's one workaround for "string in formula is too long".  Break the string into chunks and concatenate them in the formula.
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim f1 As String, f2 As String, longString As String
    
    longString = "this is a very very very very very long long long string " & _
       " which must be resolved in a value which is over 255 vcharacter" & _
       " length but i need the total length of the value. My problerm is that" & _
       " I have to do it with a user defined function and cannot separate " & _
       "the length of it. It will works for me? This was my question." & _
       String(1000, "x") '## extra long! ##
    
    'fails
    'Range("A1").Formula2 = "=LET(str,""" & longString & """,MID(str,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(str),1)),1))"
    
    'works"
    Range("A1").Formula2 = "=LET(str,""" & TextSplit(longString) & """,MID(str,ROW(OFFSET(A1,0,0,LEN(str),1)),1))"
    
End Sub

Function TextSplit(txt) As String
    Const MAX_CHUNK As Long = 200
    Dim s As String, i As Long, sep As String
    If Len(txt) > MAX_CHUNK Then
        i = 1
        Do While i < Len(txt)
            s = s & sep & Mid(txt, i, MAX_CHUNK)
            i = i + MAX_CHUNK
            sep = """ & """
        Loop
    End If
    TextSplit = s
End Function

That doesn't directly help with Evaluate but it allows you to place the formula in a cell on the sheet so it can be calculated.

I haven't the problem with placing the long text in the cell. As in the example the text is already in chunks, and the formula in the cell is correct and return the result. The problem if the formula is an array formula it cannot be assigned in this way. E.g. a="=B1:B3B4B6". In this case with Range("A1").Formula=a  formula is in the cell, but returns a #VALUE since it is an array formula. This has to be defined with FormulaArray but this not set anything in cell A1. My Excel not accept Formula2 it is 438 Error even if directly set.

Try to make it more clearer. If set in immediate window Range("A1").FormulaArray="B1:B3*B4:B6" this works seamlessly. Try to set it within the functions the cell A1 remain empty.

At least found a workaround. Within the sheet change event handler place the command which converts the Formula to FormulaArray sg. like this:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$E$6" Then
  Calculate
  Range("A1").FormulaArray = Range("A1").Formula
End If
End Sub


After this the cell became an array formula.
This solves that part to set a cell's array formula if the length of it is not longer than 255.
The remaining issue is this (Hope that found an easy way to reveal)

This is the sheet after ENTER cell E6 with the original Change event handler. If I insert the new line the code breaks Runtime error 1004. Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class
This how could be resolved. Meanwhile the max. length of a formula in a cell is 8192 (at least in my Excel version). But if I simply click on cell A1 and press CSE the formula immediately change to an array formula (with curly brackets).
I go on searching.

I don't know which version of Excel you are using, the image would point to 2010. I could check 2007 and 365 and in none of them I can reproduce the operation of this event macro if the length of FormulaArray exceeds 255 characters.
In my opinion, it is not possible to set the FormulaArray property with a macro, in which the length of the definition exceeds 255 characters. The only solution I can see is to replace parts of this definition with names.

Yes 2010. What i not understand, if Formula can be set in this way why not the array variant. Meanwhile another issue. After manually set it to arrayformula in immediate pane type ?range("A1").Formulaarray="=LEN(""this is a very very very very very long long long string which must be resolved in a value which is over 255 vcharacter""&"&""" length but i need the total length of the value. My problerm is that I have to do it with a user defined function and cannot separate the length of it. It will works for me? This was my question."")" returns TRUE.  Try Set to this value: Error 1004.

For me to replace in an embedded string formula the different functions with names and create the formula in this way is much beyond my strait limits. So than maybe a stuck at limiting the length to 255. Thanks.

Excel is not the same as VBA. VBA only models Excel. This is where the differences come from. In Excel, you can create an array formula longer than 255 characters, in VBA it can be read, but it cannot be modified. There are also other differences, e.g. in VBA there are no local versions of FormulaArray.
